# Need a database that supports both 32 and 64bit environments

Tags: c#, database

I have developed an application which uses MS Access database (provider = microsoft jet) which works on my 32 bit OS, but not on 64 bit OSes.

What databases can I use instead that can be used on both 32 and 64bit environments and can be developed on a 32bit machine?

I am using VS2008, so please make sure i can use tools provided by VS to use the db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server Express edition would be a good starting point. Depends how heavy weight you want it. If you want a fairly minimal database, try SQLite.

Comment: +1, if you're familiar with the MS tools, then SQL Server Express edition is a good choice

Answer (score 1):

Typically, you're going to use an 'enterprise' capable database; the big three players (to me at least), are going to be MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server.

However, you need to define what is 'best' - what criteria determine which database you need? Each database server type has it's advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL Server, any edition or MySQL/PostgreSQL for open source versions. Access will have issues with scalability as well if you are concerned with that.

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 Express Edition Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/it-it/details.aspx?FamilyID=01af61e6-2f63-4291-bcad-fd500f6027ff)

Requisiti di sistema

Sistemi operativi supportatiWindows 7;Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2;Windows Server 2008;Windows Server 2008 R2;Windows Vista Service Pack 1;Windows XP Service Pack 3
Sistemi a 32 bit
Computer con processore Intel o compatibile a 1 GHz o più veloce (consigliato 2 GHz o più veloce. È supportato solo un processore singolo).
Almeno 256 MB di RAM (consigliato almeno 1 GB).
1 GB di spazio libero su disco rigido.
Sistemi a 64 bit
Processore a 1,4 GHz o più veloce (consigliato 2 GHz o più veloce. È supportato solo un processore singolo).
Almeno 256 MB di RAM (consigliato almeno 1 GB).
1 GB di spazio libero su disco rigido.